# How to read ordereddict from json

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, ordereddict

i have a json like,

```
d = {"id": 1, "company_car": 1, "manufacture_stage": OrderedDict([("id", 4), ("company", OrderedDict([("id", 1), ("name", "BMW"), ("icon", "http://test.com/ta/")]))]), "manufacture_car_stage_status": "Scheduled", "start_datetime": "2019-04-30 17:24:32", "end_datetime": "2019-05-30 17:54:32", "taken_datetime": None, "is_active": true, "manufacture_car_stage_detail": {"assessment_scores": None}, "is_shortlisted": false, "is_rejected": false}
```

how can i get `name` which has `BMW`  value form oderedDict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access keys of [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) in same way as in normal dictionary

```
d['manufacture_stage']['company']['name']
```